# Which Tense should I put after "once/ as soon as" in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense

I'd like to know which tense I should put after "once" (or as soon as) in these examples

> I will wash the dishes as soon as  she **is**/ **will have finished**  / **has finished**
>
> I would have washed the dishes once she **had finished** / **was finished**
>
> I will do it once you **have gotten** / **got** / **get** out of this house!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, "has finished," "had finished," and "have gotten."

Colloquially, you'd be likely to hear "is finished," "was finished," and "get."

Comment: Or "have got" in British English.